# Change bluehost email address in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, email, bluehost

Hello guys i'm new to wordpress

I wanted to know if it is possible to change the default sender address of bluehost i.e name@box####.bluehost.com to name@yourdomain.com

I'm using a plugin called Email before download which sends email to the people who download files from my website.The mail is sent from name@box####.bluehost.com.

If I try to change the sender email address from email-before-download.php file of Email before download plugin it's not working it still display the default address name@box####.bluehost.com
how can I change that sender email address in this case?

Is there any plugin which does that? or we have to change it from the bluehost cpanel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login to cPanel > File Manager > public_html > php.ini > edit

Search for sendmail keyword .
You will find this
; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i

Please add : -f'user@domain.com'

Eg: sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f'user@domain.com'

Answer (score 0):

I found the same problem.

I got to this thread by searching for it.

But I have hit upon a solution. It requires tinkering with a WordPress core file though. If you are not comfortable with it, you may desist from doing it. I am referring to WordPress 2.7 only.

I found in pluggable.php in wp-includes around line 343:

```
$from_name = 'WordPress';
```

I changed it to:

```
$from_name = $blog_title;
```

Then around line 354:

```
$from_email = 'wordpress@' . $sitename;
```

I changed that to:

```
$from_email = 'administrator@' . $sitename;
```

That's it.
Maybe there is a more elegant way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [add_filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter) to achieve this.

Just add this code in your themes `function.php`

```
add_filter('wp_mail_from', 'wp_change_default_email_change_from_email');
add_filter('wp_mail_from_name', 'wp_change_default_email_change_from_name');

function wp_change_default_email_change_from_email()
{
    $from_email = 'name@yourdomain.com';

    return $from_email;
}

function wp_change_default_email_change_from_name() {
    
    $from_name = 'name';

    return $from_name;
}
```

This updates the default from email and from email address.

Comment: Changing this wont stop the functioning of my live site right?

Comment: For all the emails going out from your system, the from name and email will be one specified here. It will not affect the functioning of your site.

Comment: I changed it when i was running my site on localhost using xampp it worked. But when i make the same change on my live site its not reflecting still its displays box####@bluehost.com what should be done?